# Set of critical points

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $\Omega $ be a bounded doamin with lipschitz boundary, $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.  Is it true that if  $f\in C^1(\overline \Omega) $  and it is strictly positive in $\Omega $. Then the set $$\left\lbrace x\in \Omega, \nabla f=0\right\rbrace. $$ is compact?

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Comment: Not if $\Omega$ is not compact (taking any strictly positive constant function).

Answer (score 1):

If $\Omega$ is an open set this set need not be compact: take $f \equiv 1$.